# What suits best for Hyperledger fabric while Integration?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ipfs, bigchaindb

I'm currently trying to figure out on couple of things

1)  What blockchain databases can be integrated with hyperledger fabric – (such as IPDB, or Bigchain db or couchDb)

2)  What distributed file systems can be integrated with hyperledger fabric (such as IPFS, StorJ, Swarm).

can someone add your views, if there is anything better please share.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such limitations, many people use integration patterns with various other technologies, for example:

- Clients can write data to a distributed file system or database and then put a link and/or hash of the data on the Fabric blockchain as permanent evidence of the data.
- Clients can listen for block events on a Fabric peer, and as blocks are committed to Fabric, write the data to another distributed file system or database.

The possibilities are endless.